# Docker and Laravel Cache issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, caching

I have lots of issues with cache using docker and Laravel.
I am running the docker desktop on MAC OS Ventura, a Macbook Pro laptop.

I have about 15 containers, but not all are running. Out of those, I have 3 containers running Laravel on different ports, and I have another container running MySQL.

For Laravel apps to connect to MySQL, I put all these containers on the same docker network. So on the browser, I can just call each of the Laravel apps based on port, and it works mostly.

Now when I work on one of the Laravel apps, development works fine most of the time. But then, once every 5 to 10 days, Laravel cache blocks me from reflecting changes, especially if I do changes to routes and controllers. I tried all artisan commands to clear it, like:

- `php artisan config:cache`
- `php artisan view:cache`
- `php artisan view:clear`

And still does not see the change. Then I restart the container, it works a little better but is not consistent.

Then my last solution was to stop all my containers. And restart the docker desktop. Then everything goes back to normal, and I can see my changes for every change I do to the code.

My question is, why does only restarting the docker desktop effectively fix the issue? Is there a better way to do this? Or maybe something is wrong with the way I set up many containers on my Mac.

Any input or hint is appreciated.
Here is my docker file:

```
    version: '2'
services:
  api_composition:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/laravel:10
    ports:
      - '8016:8000'
    volumes:
      - './ApiComposition:/app'
```

Comment: Show the docker-compose.yml and the Dockerfile you're using. It might be the way you created thevolume

Comment: Laravel does not cache source code changes. That might be opcache (though for development you shouldn't really be using it), or there's something else in your container setup that is causing it

Comment: Hi UnderDog, I added the docker file above to my question

Comment: Hi apokryfos,
Thanks for your reply. Just to be clear, I didn't mean my code is cached, i mean i don't see the simple change in browser.
It is even as simple this. 
I have 
    echo "Hello 123". 
So I see "Hello 123" in browser. 
Then I change it to
     echo "Hello 456", 
then I still see Hello 123 in browser !!

And not of "php artisan cache:clear", or other commands resolved the issue. 
It got fixed only after I restart the Docker Desktop !!

Comment: Make a route and put the command `phpinfo()` in it. Check for any OPCache related configuration, if any, and try to disable it if it's enabled or at least configure it to re-check the source files on every request. Also try using a hard refresh (CTRL+F5) in your browser to clear any browser caches. What you are describing does sound like code caching.

Comment: The Zend OPcache is disabled


    / Opcode Caching  Disabled
   /  Optimization  Disabled
   /  SHM Cache  Enabled
   /   File Cache  Disabled
  /   JIT  On